# Ignore spurious wakeups, condition_variable::wait_for

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

Documentation says that the second overload with the Predicate can be used to avoid spurious wakeups. I'm not seeing it, how can I modify my code to ensure that wait_for is not spuriously awakened?

```
while(count_ > 0) {
    if (condition_.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(timeOut_)) ==
            std::cv_status::timeout)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Put a lambda as predicate, as shown in the [reference's example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is misleading: there are possibly spurios wake-ups but `wait_for()` with a predicate will only return when the predicates us `true`. That is, when using the predicate version it appears as if there are no spurious wake-ups. You can possibly detect if there were spurious wake-ups by recording how often the predicate got executed.

You'd use it like

```
if (condition_.wait_for(lock,
                        std::chrono::milliseconds(timeOut_),
                        [&](){ return count_ <= 0; }) ==
        std::cv_status::timeout) {
    // deal with timeout here
}
```

Comment: Still, the distinction is an important one when using timeouts, depending on your requirments with a timeout you'd have to re-calculate the timeout in case a spurious wakeup occurs - which (presumably) the wait_for() overload that don't expose the spurious wakeups would do for you.

Comment: @nos I don't think it actually recalculates the timeout, look at wait_until documentation, it looks like it just starts the timer over again.

Comment: @SteveM: according to 30.5.1 [thread.condition.condvar] paragragh 38 the call to `wait_for()` is equivalent to a call to `wait_until()` with the time calculated as `chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time`. So, it doesn't recalculate the the relative time but it also doesn't restart with the same time-out.